Seeking with ss dont seem to work in combination with VideoFilter
In FFMPEG I am using the following command to extract frames from a video:
ffmpeg -ss "00:47:13" -i "Video.webm" -vf select="gte(n, 90000)" -vframes 5000 "frames_%d.jpg"
My thought here was to fast seek to a point before the mark of the next frames to be selected to make the select faster.
But for me the Seeking either doesn't happen or takes huge additional time to seek. But isn't -ss used to fast seek to a position?
Time to extract 5000 Frames:
Time without seeking: 337 Seconds
Time with seeking: 379 Seconds
Is there a case in which the -ss doesn't work as it should?

For benchmarking the seeking effect, I recommend you to test with single output file (e.g -vframes 1). The reason that the seeking is not reducing the duration, is that gte(n, 90000) counts 90000 from the seeking position (not from the beginning of the file). Assuming 30fps, subtract 84990 frames from 90000 (applying 90000 frames from the beginning of the file): ffmpeg -ss "00:47:13" -i "Video.webm" -vf select="gte(n, 5010)" -vframes 5000 "frames_%d.jpg"

@Rotem let me check...

@Rotem It seems to work properly! Thats fantastic. Maybe you could at it as an answer so I can accept it :)

The reason that the seeking is not reducing the duration, is that gte(n, 90000) counts 90000 from the seeking position (not from the beginning of the file).
Assuming 30fps, subtract 84990 frames from 90000 (applying 90000 frames from the beginning of the file):
ffmpeg -ss "00:47:13" -i "Video.webm" -vf select="gte(n, 5010)" -vframes 5000 "frames_%d.jpg"

